# How to get better performance query result on filtering data

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework

I have query that needs to filter large set of data by some search criteria.

The search is happening through 3 tables: Products, ProductPrimaryCodes, ProductCodes.

The large data (given there is around 2000 records, so is not that large, but is largest by the other tables data) set is in ProductCodes table.

Here is an example of what I've done.

```
var result = products.Where(x => x.Code.Contains(se) || 
                                 x.ProductPrimaryCodes.Any(p => p.Code.Contains(se)) || 
                                 x.ProductCodes.Any(p => p.Code.Contains(se)))
                     .Select(x => new ProductDto
                                      {
                                          Id = x.Id,
                                          Name = x.Name,
                                          InStock = x.InStock,
                                          BrandId = (BrandType)x.BrandId,
                                          Code = x.Code,
                                          CategoryName = x.Category.Name,
                                          SubCategoryName = x.SubCategory.Name,
                                      });
```

The time that query executes is around 8-9 sec, so i believe is quite long for this kind of search. And just a note, without doing `ProductCodes.Any()`, the query executes in less than a second and retrieves result to the page.

ProductCodes table:

```
Id,
Code,
ProductId
```

Any suggestions how to get better performance of the query?

Comment: First thing to do for you (because we can't): check the SQL query execution plan. Performance question are invariably hard to answer based on nothing but a LINQ statement.

Comment: The query doesn't execute in less than a second - it hasn't executed at all. Because it is LINQ the query won't execute until you materialise the results by doing a ToList() or Any().

Comment: Try to enable EF debugging and see what SQL query is producing this code.  Check also if the relationship is properly defined. Sometimes these persistence frameworks are doing weird things, nothing like old SQL code.

Comment: +1 to request for execution plan, but I also have a question, will you be able to add indexes to the database? Im suspect we're seeing a lot of nested table scans here (aka giant for loops that scan the entire database many times) which can be optimised somewhat using indexes.

Comment: Thanks, i will for sure consider adding indexes, and debug EF. For now i've found a solution that works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that worked for me.

```
        var filteredProductsByCode = products.Where(x => x.Code.Contains(se));
        var filteredProducts = products.Where(x => x.ProductCodes.Any(p => p.Code.Contains(se)) 
                                             || x.ProductPrimaryCodes.Any(p => p.Code.Contains(se)));

        return filteredProductsByCode.Union(filteredProducts).Select(x => new ProductDto
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Name = x.Name,
            InStock = x.InStock,
            BrandId = (BrandType)x.BrandId,
            Code = x.Code,
            CategoryName = x.Category.Name,
            SubCategoryName = x.SubCategory.Name,
        }).OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)
```

Clearly not the cleanest, but I will also consider introducing stored procedures for this kind of queries.

Comment: Likely what is killing your query performance is the use of `Contains` for all of the code evaluations. With `==` checks your initial query should not have any real issues, even a `StartsWith` would likely be faster. Querying with likely left outer joins for ProductCodes/ProductPrimaryCodes with the equivalent of '%a%' or the like x3 isn't going to be fast.  I'd suspect if x.ProductPrimaryCodes doesn't impose a performance issue on it's own, but x.ProductCodes does then there is a loose association. Execution plans from SQL Server will reveal a lot.